# Python: smtplib: エラー「AttributeError: module 'smtplib' has no attribute 'SMTP'」

Tags: python, python3, gmail

Python3でsmtp.logを使ってGmailでメールを出そうとすると「AttributeError: module 'smtplib' has no attribute 'SMTP'」と言われます。何が悪いか教えてください。

**batchMailerOne.py**

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
#
# batchMailerOne.py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#### START CUSTOMIZATION ####
smtp_host     = 'smtp.gmail.com'
smtp_port     = 587
from_email    = 'foo <foo@example.com>'
mail_subject  = 'bar'
user_name     = 'xxxxx no such mail xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com' # Gmail login name
user_password = 'xxxxxxxxx' # Gmail psswd (2 steps authorization is not supported)

# set mail address surrounded in double quote, ended with comma (you can send up to 100 mails a day)
to_emails = [
        "recipient1 <recipient1@example.com>",
        "recipient2 <recipient2@example.com>",
        "recipient3 <recipient2@example.com>",
]

# write your message between ''' and '''
message_text = '''
Dear someone,

Hello
'''

### END CUSTOMIZATION ###

from email import message
import smtplib

server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_host, smtp_port)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.ehlo()
server.login(user_name, user_password)

for to_email in to_emails:
        msg            = message.EmailMessage()
        msg.set_content(message_text)
        msg['Subject'] = mail_subject
        msg['From']    = from_email
        msg['To']      = to_email
        server.send_message(msg)

server.quit()
```

**実行時のエラー**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cf\batchMailerOne.py", line 31, in <module>
    import smtplib
  File "C:\Users\cf\Anaconda3\lib\smtplib.py", line 49, in <module>
    import email.generator
  File "C:\Users\cf\Anaconda3\lib\email\generator.py", line 14, in <module>
    from copy import deepcopy
  File "C:\Users\cf\Anaconda3\lib\copy.py", line 60, in <module>
    from org.python.core import PyStringMap
  File "C:\Users\cf\batchMailerOne.py", line 39, in <module>
    server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_host, smtp_port)
AttributeError: module 'smtplib' has no attribute 'SMTP'
```

**Python バージョン**

```
C:\Users\cf>\Users\cf\Anaconda3\python.exe -V
Python 3.6.3 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

Comment: エラーメッセージに `from org.python.core import PyStringMap` という部分があって、質問文が編集される前は、その直後が `"C:\Users\cf\...\batchMailer\Resources\org.py"` となっていました。つまり、`org.py` という名前のファイルが batchMailer フォルダの中に存在している事が原因ではないでしょうか。

Comment: metropolisさん、ありがとうございます。org.pyだと分かりづらいと思い、batchMailer.pyとしましたが同じエラーになりました。

Comment: もしかして、バイトコンパイルされた `org.pyc` というファイルが `batchMailer\Resources` フォルダに残っていたりしないでしょうか？

Comment: スミマセン、おっしゃる通りに近い状況でした。。org.pyを消したら消えました。

Comment: 100%わたしのケアレスミスです。無事メールを送信できました。すみません＆ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

もしかして、バイトコンパイルされた `org.pyc` というファイルが `batchMailer\Resources` フォルダに残っていたりしないでしょうか？

<sub>-- これは、[metropolis](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/16894/metropolis) さんの[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/49945/python-smtplib-%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC-attributeerror-module-smtplib-has-no-attribute-smtp#comment52103_49945)をコミュニティ wiki 回答として投稿するものです。</sub>

Answer (score 0):

私の(anacondaでない、素の)環境では、もっと先でエラーになりました。
Anacondaで作成された環境に問題があると想像します。

```
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials t4-v6sm41336798pfh.45 - gsmtp')
```

Comment: おお、そうですか。私はanacondaしか使ったことがありません。さらに調査します。